# Why i'm getting exception No connection could be made when trying to send data to a server?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the method:

```
private void SendDataToServer()
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://10.0.0.2:8080 ");
            request.Method = "POST";
            string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
```

1. Maybe the port 8080 i didn't use it right ?
2. The string i should send to the server should be in this format:

   "http://10.0.0.2:8080/?say=hello world"

   The same when i type it in chrome browser when i type: http://10.0.0.2:8080/?say=hello world

The part http://10.0.0.2:8080/?say= should never change.
Only the text after it hello world if i will change it to hello everyone or anything else. But the left part http://10.0.0.2:8080/?say= should never change.

The exception is on the line:

```
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
```

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I checked in chrome i can send hello world: http://10.0.0.2:8080/?say=hello world

Comment: In Chrome, however, you're hitting it with a GET request--it's not an apples to apples comparison. The host could be refusing your POST request because it's a POST request.

Comment: There is a space character in your uri: `"http://10.0.0.2:8080 "`

Comment: I'ts working with POST but when i did:  WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://10.0.0.2:8080/?say=hello? im here "); so it's saying speaking hello? im here on my android smartphone. I just wonder what is the strigng postData do ? What is this string for ? I'm not using the string in it .

Answer (score 0):

HTTP POST messages can include a *body*, a block of data, in your example the `postData` variable is sent as the body of the message.

Besides that block of data, you can send a *query string*, which is a number of key/value pairs included in the request URI, in the form `?key1=value1&key2=value2`.

The server can choose to process either the query string, the body, or both, and the server you're communicating with chooses to process the query string.

However the error message "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" is more likely to be caused by the space character added to the request URI: `"http://10.0.0.2:8080 "`.